# Do we need the "legal" and "legislation" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that [this question here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38735/can-state-or-local-laws-regulate-where-aircraft-can-take-off-and-land) has a "legal" tag and a "legislation" tag.

- Do we need both of them?
- Should we keep one of them and synonym the other?
- Do we need any of them at all?

These tags currently have a very low question linkage. We already have tags specific to aviation regulations, for example "faa-regulations".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, a legal tag that's separate from a regulations tag is useful for legal issues that aren't covered by aviation regulations. And the very few questions we have so far do seem to reflect that, e.g.:

- [State/local laws on landing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38735/62)
- [State/local requirements for pilot registration](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26462/62)

But I don't think we need both the tags we have today: I would remove [legislation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation) completely and use only [legal](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal). It's a simpler, broader term that's likely to be more useful. There are so few questions that it can easily be done manually.

I don't really know what we should do about countries or jurisdictions: laws are different everywhere and that's why we have multiple regulations tags. The same logic applies to legal questions but we have so few today that I think individual tags like [legal-us](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-us) (USA) or [legal-fr](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-fr) (France) etc. would be overkill. I'd leave it alone for now and let people indicate the jurisdiction by combining [legal](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) with other tags like [international](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international) or whatever. That seems to be what people are already doing anyway, and unless/until we have a large number of non-regulation legal questions, I don't see any point in trying to do more.

Comment: I think that a lot of questions that would fall into this category just use the country tag and then ask the question.  I'm not entirely sure that the legal tag is even really needed, but I wouldn't think that the legal-xxx tags would be needed when you could use two tags.

Answer (score 1):

*A bit too late, but there goes nothing:*

We do **not** need [legal](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal). Its description says:

> Refers to any question related to the application of laws in aviation

Which is what regulations are for, since regulations (e.g. [14 CFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Aviation_Regulations#FAR_vs._14_CFR)) have the force of law (e.g. [US Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Code)). (The two examples in @Pondlife's answer already have tags for regulations.)

Note: a generic [regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulations) tag exists and is used 207 times.

There are [12 questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blegal%5D%20closed%3A0%20-%5Bregulations%5D%20-%5Bfaa-regulations%5D) that are tagged with [legal] but not [faa/regulations]. After [perusing them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAg0H.png), 3 of them are IMO off-topic, and 9 are mislabeled (wrong tag usage).

Due to the vagueness of the description, it leads to [questions being asked and closed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/73279/14897).

IMO [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) is the best place for a question that needs statutes and/or past court cases, i.e. the il/legality of a topic.

Comment: Reviewing the [legal] questions (30 ATM), I find quite a few that are generic legal questions related to aviation, but not specific about specific regulations. E.g. [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44117/3386), [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44363/3386), [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38223/3386), [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50822/3386).

Comment: @kevin: 3 of your 4 are in my [perusing them] link (please check it). Also the reason I omitted those tagged with regulations (check my custom search), is precisely to omit the generic ones.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it is clickable, you should include it in the post! My view is we should keep the tag for country-generic questions, and I don't think it is harmful to keep those questions. Most of them get a satisfactory answer, and the volume is really low. Of course if legal questions start flooding in, we'll need to do something.

Comment: @kevin: My aim was to keep the post short. For "country-generic questions", the generic [regulations] is enough IMO. If we venture into the statutes and codes (actual law), then really it's become Law.SE. (I'm happy to continue this in The Hangar.)