# Tag merge: [legal] → [regulations]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

During a discussion I had with @ymb1 on "[Do we need the "legal" and "legislation" tags?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3263)", we came to the idea of merging the [legal](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) tag to [regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulations).

The description for [legal](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) is

> Refers to any question related to the application of laws in aviation

This description sounds broad to me, and might introduce questions that are largely unrelated to aviation. Now that [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) is established, questions that focus on the legal aspect should be redirected there, where answers can quote legislation and court cases.

The description for [regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulations) is

> Regulations governing aviation worldwide or in any jurisdiction. Specific jurisdictions should use a more specific tag.

which is sufficient for country-generic questions.

At the moment we have 207 [regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulations) questions and only 30 [legal](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) questions. My view is that most of the latter can be re-tagged to the former, while a small amount of them are off-topic on this site.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: How is this a different question to the linked?

Comment: @Jamiec the linked is about "legal" vs "legislation". This one is "legal" vs "regulations".

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread that.

Answer (score 5):

I agree. Further,

1. Legal is misused due to its vagueness.

Of the 30 legal questions, [only 12](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blegal%5D%20-%5Bregulations%5D%20-%5Bfaa-regulations%5D%20closed%3A0) are not closed and do not share a regulations tag (either the FAA one or the generic one). Of those 12, there are 9 where either [regulations] suffices, or neither apply (mislabeled).

2. Leads to questions that aren't really related to aviation, as explained by @RonBeyer [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/73279/14897):

> The tag description is "Refers to any question related to the application of laws in aviation." This is not the application of laws in aviation, this is about liability for an accident. This isn't any different than a Mexican registered bus travelling a road/city in Mexico that the [US Government says is dangerous](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/mexico-travel-advisory.html) and asking if the Mexican travel company is liable, exactly the same with the word "airplane" replaced with "bus".

3. We haven't agreed to answer based on codes/statutes, [only regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (supposing legal means law, which isn't clear to begin with).

Comment: In general, the [legal] tag tends to lead to people asking legal questions (elsewhere on SE). It's just too vague

Comment: All but 30 of our questions are illegal‽

Answer (score 1):

So curiously, the tag [regulation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulation) was blacklisted a long time ago because it is vague and non-specific see the question: [Remove regulation tag while we still can?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/66/69)

That's also when we came up with our current system of tagging questions related to regulations, and which specifies the jurisdiction (and sometimes part).

It seems that people have just come up with new ways to add a very similar tag, and both [regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulations) and [legal](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) should probably just be blacklisted after being retagged with the appropriate CAA-specific tag.

Comment: @ymb1 Thanks for the edit, but the original tag which was blacklisted **was** [tag:regulation], and not [tag:regulations] that we are discussing here.  They are so closely related though, that I think that it is relevant, and why I said that people have just come up with new ways to add the same tag.  Except that it isn't the same, lol....

Comment: Good finding. My question is still, what do we do about questions that are generic and not specific to a jurisdiction? Or should we always require a jurisdiction, like Law.SE?

Comment: @kevin If it's a legal question, I believe that we should always require a jurisdiction, because otherwise the question is basically unanswerable.  The community does a good job now of asking for clarification when someone doesn't specify, and getting the appropriate tags on the question.